# I am getting issue in getting the domain name from the url in next js getServerSideProps, but on Vercel it works fine and did'nt work on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js13, aws-application-load-balancer

I am getting issue in getting the domain name from the url in next js getServerSideProps, but on Vercel it works fine and did'nt work on aws, using:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { req, res, query } = context;

  let hostName = req.headers["host"];

  const formattedHostName= hostName.replace(/^(https?:\/\/)?([^\/]+)(\/.*)?$/, "$2");
  let metadata = null;
  let response = null;

  try {
    response = await axios.get(
      `${process.env.API_URL}/api/site/get-site-data-by-domainname/${formattedHostName}`
    );

    metadata = response?.data?.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error-in-getServerSideProps ",error);
  }

  return {
    props: {
      metadata,
    },
  };
}
```

In here I am using req.headers["host"] to get the host like (google.com) but instead on aws it returning the ip address or the localhost address of the aws instance like 127.0.0.1:35453 and on vercel it is working fine I am stuck on this issue I want this to work on AWS as well.

I have tried to fetch the hostName from the next js middleware but, I think there no much time gap in both middleware.js and getServerSideProps execution, so it gets undefined, basically I am trying to get the referer from middleware.js and pass it as

`NextResponse.next().headers.set("x-host", request.headers.get("referer"));`

this works but, after the getServerSideProps gets executed.